# Two domains within the same IP Range

Tags: active-directory, virtualization

We are in the process of implementing MS Dynamics AX and a requirement by our consultants is to have a test environment. We can build this environment and let it use our live AD setup however I wish to avoid this and keep the production setup only for the Live Dynamics install.

The quesiton I have is, since we are installing this test environment on virtual machines and hosting it on a virtual server (HyperV) that is on the current live domain, when we install a virtual machine and promote it to a domain controller to host the demo environment (requirement for Dynamics) will both the demo Active Directory and production Active Directory setups interfere with each other on any note?

I'm a little worried about having both domains running.

(Separate IP range can be used but would make things extremely complicate)
(Restricted to only local VM to VM traffic can be used but the servers need outside access)

Thanks!

windows server 2012r2 (to be test domain)
windows server 2008 (current live domain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an AD perspective: Only if the two domains have the same NETBIOS name.

That said, if you're doing to run DHCP, or anything multicast/broadcast related in the test environment, it should have its own subnet. It's not very difficult to configure this in Hyper-V

Comment: There wont be any DHCP services but there will be DNS for AD.
It would also have to use the same subnet so users can connect to both the test environment using TESTDOMAIN\User at the same time as connecting to their local production domain (they obviously have eparate usernames for their production login). Do you see any issues?

Comment: Why does what you've mentioned mean that it **has** to use the same subnet? Nothing you've said makes that a requirement.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance then - can you explain how it would be done?
My aim is to have the users on the 10.0.0.x range be able to communicate with for example 192.168.50.x range that way isolating all traffic. Aside from using routers?

Comment: Why does it have to avoid using routers? That's how a router works. I'm not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish here, you seem to have some wild requirements for some reason.

Comment: We are not all as clever as you MDMarra. I am simply trying to understand if there is any issue running two domains on the same subnet and if any cross communication would occour between them causing issues. If you feel the question is too annoying or too simple for you to answer you can just ignore it.

Comment: Why are you upset? I've answered your question and I've answered your unrelated follow ups. If you feel overwhelmed by this issue, you should ask your manager for some formal training.

Comment: I am not upset - Sometimes your answers are a little derogative and you wouldn't neccessary notice. Anyway, thanks.